# Row for every third element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Im would like to have a  container around every third  element - However, cant quite get it to work, im trying to do it like this:

```
<xsl:when test="$type != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="query" select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and type = $type ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($query) &gt; 0">
                <section class="brochures-{$section-css-name}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'portrait' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Business</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'landscape' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Panorama</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'quadrat' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Image</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or position() mod 3 = 0 ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="case-shadow">&nbsp;<xsl:comment/>
                            </div>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$query">
                                <xsl:variable name="externalUrl" select="externalUrl"/>
                                <xsl:if test="$externalUrl != ''">
                                    <article class="brochure">
                                        <a href="{$externalUrl}/MailView/" target="_blank" class="replaceURL">
                                            <xsl:if test="$type = 60">
                                                <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="160" height="228" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$type = 61">
                                                <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="228" height="160" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$type = 62">
                                                <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <p>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </article>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                </section>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
```

I would like the output of the HTML to be:

```
<section class="brochures-portrait">
<h2>Business</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="case-shadow">&nbsp;<!----></div>
    <article class="brochure">
    </article>
    <article class="brochure">
    </article>
    <article class="brochure">
    </article>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="case-shadow">&nbsp;<!----></div>
    <article class="brochure">
    </article>
    <article class="brochure">
    </article>
</div>  
</section>
```

However, i only get 1  around all of my brochure s :(

---

Ok, thx, but im not quite sure how to integrate that with this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="chosenregion">
        <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('region')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$currentPage/showRegionNavgation = '1'">
        <nav class="region-sort">
            <ul>
                <li class="grey-gradient">
                    <xsl:if test="$chosenregion = ''">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <a href="?">All</a>
                </li>
                <li class="grey-gradient">
                    <xsl:if test="$chosenregion = '76'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <a href="?region=76">North</a>
                </li>
                <li class="grey-gradient">
                    <xsl:if test="$chosenregion = '77'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <a href="?region=77">Mid</a>
                </li>
                <li class="grey-gradient last">
                    <xsl:if test="$chosenregion = '78'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <a href="?region=78">South</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:call-template name="brochure">
        <xsl:with-param name="type">60</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="region">
            <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('region')"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="section-css-name">portrait</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="brochure">
        <xsl:with-param name="type">61</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="region">
            <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('region')"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="section-css-name">landscape</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="brochure">
        <xsl:with-param name="type">62</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="region">
            <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('region')"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="section-css-name">quadrat</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="brochure">
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <xsl:param name="section-css-name"/>
    <xsl:param name="region"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$region != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="query" select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and type = $type and region = $region ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($query) &gt; 0">
                <section class="brochures-{$section-css-name}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'portrait' or region = $region">
                            <h2>
                                <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Business')"/>
                            </h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'landscape' or region = $region">
                            <h2>
                                <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Panorama')"/>
                            </h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'quadrat' or region = $region">
                            <h2>
                                <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Image')"/>
                            </h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <div class="case-shadow">&nbsp;<xsl:comment/>
                    </div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$query">
                        <xsl:variable name="externalUrl" select="externalUrl"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$externalUrl != ''">
                            <article class="brochure">
                                <a href="{$externalUrl}/MailView/" target="_blank" class="replaceURL">
                                    <xsl:if test="$type = 60">
                                        <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="176" height="248" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$type = 61">
                                        <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="242" height="170" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$type = 62">
                                        <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="176" height="175" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <p>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                            </article>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </section>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$type != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="query" select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and type = $type ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($query) &gt; 0">
                <section class="brochures-{$section-css-name}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'portrait' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Business</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'landscape' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Panorama</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'quadrat' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Image</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <div class="case-shadow">&nbsp;<xsl:comment/>
                    </div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$query">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = 1 or position() mod 3 = 0">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <xsl:variable name="externalUrl" select="externalUrl"/>
                                    <xsl:if test="$externalUrl != ''">
                                        <article class="brochure">
                                            <a href="{$externalUrl}/MailView/" target="_blank" class="replaceURL">
                                                <xsl:if test="$type = 60">
                                                    <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="160" height="228" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$type = 61">
                                                    <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="228" height="160" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$type = 62">
                                                    <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <p>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
                                                </p>
                                            </a>
                                        </article>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:variable name="externalUrl" select="externalUrl"/>
                                <xsl:if test="$externalUrl != ''">
                                    <article class="brochure">
                                        <a href="{$externalUrl}/MailView/" target="_blank" class="replaceURL">
                                            <xsl:if test="$type = 60">
                                                <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="160" height="228" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$type = 61">
                                                <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="228" height="160" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$type = 62">
                                                <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <p>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </article>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </section>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="query" select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and type = $type and region = $region ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($query) &gt; 0">
                <section class="brochures-{$section-css-name}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'portrait' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Business</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'landscape' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Panorama</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$section-css-name = 'quadrat' or region = $region">
                            <h2>Image</h2>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <div class="case-shadow">&nbsp;<xsl:comment/>
                    </div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$query">
                        <xsl:variable name="externalUrl" select="externalUrl"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$externalUrl != ''">
                            <article class="brochure">
                                <a href="{$externalUrl}/MailView/" target="_blank" class="replaceURL">
                                    <xsl:if test="$type = 60">
                                        <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="176" height="248" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$type = 61">
                                        <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="242" height="170" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$type = 62">
                                        <img src="{$externalUrl}/MailView/pagedata/frontpage.jpg" width="176" height="175" alt="" class="reflect"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <p>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                            </article>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </section>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This sort of thing should be straight-forward, but can you post your input XML, as well as your expected output, just so there is no confusion about what you expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over all your elements, and determing the position of each one, instead in turn, you should try and match the relevant element in the 1st, 4th, 7th (etc) position.

For example, suppose your input XML was as follows

```
<brochures>
   <brochure>Brochure 1</brochure>
   <brochure>Brochure 2</brochure>
   <brochure>Brochure 3</brochure>
   <brochure>Brochure 4</brochure>
   <brochure>Brochure 5</brochure>
</brochures>
```

You would get every third element like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="brochure[position() mod 3 = 1]" mode="first"/>
```

Once positioned on such rows, you can then just write out your div, and then match the three rows required in that group.

```
<div class="row">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 3]"/>
</div>
```

Here is the full XSLT. Note I have parameterised the number of rows per div to make it more configurable.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="rows" select="3" />

   <xsl:template match="/brochures">
      <section>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="brochure[position() mod $rows = 1]" mode="first"/>
      </section>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="brochure" mode="first">
      <div class="row">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $rows]"/>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="brochure">
      <article class="brochure"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note the use of the **mode** to distinguish between the two template matching the **brochure** element)

When applied to the sample XML above, the following is returned

```
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <article class="brochure" />
    <article class="brochure" />
    <article class="brochure" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <article class="brochure" />
    <article class="brochure" />
   </div>
</section>
```

Hopefully this gives you enough information to adapt it to you own XML!